# How to notify database changes with signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've just started with SignalR and would like to try out the real time notifications. The objective is to keep displaying the updated message on web page. 
There is a database table - `DummyData` with a column `Message`. This table has only one record - `Hello`
When the page loads, "Hello" is displayed.

I then manually run the command  in sql server 2012

`update DummyData set Message='hello world'`, but the message isn't updated in the webpage.

**aspx:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var notify = $.connection.notificationsHub;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            notify.server.notifyAllClients();
        });

        notify.client.displayNotification = function (msg) {               
            $("#newData").html(msg);
        };

        notify.client.stopClient = function () {
            $.connection.hub.stop();
        };
    });
</script>
 <span id="newData"></span>
```

**aspx.cs:**

```
public string SendNotifications()
    {
      string message = string.Empty;
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
       {
        string query = "SELECT [Message] FROM [dbo].[DummyData]";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
        command.Notification = null;
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
         reader.Read();
         message = reader[0].ToString();
        }
       }            
        return message;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SendNotifications();
        }            
    }
```

**NotificationsHub.cs**

```
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
 Messages obj = new Messages();
 public void NotifyAllClients(string msg)
  {
   IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
   context.Clients.All.displayNotification(msg);
  }

 public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
  {
   NotifyAllClients();
   return base.OnConnected();
  }

 public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
 {
  NotifyAllClients();
  return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
 }
}
```

**global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(Constr);
        }
```

When I run the tsql update command, the break point is first hit at `dependency_OnChange` and I can see the new updated text being returned from `SendNotification`. But it isn't seen reflected on page. Feels like I'm almost there but something is missing.

Comment: Just as a hint, try overriding the `OnConnected`, `OnDisconnected`, and `OnReconnected` events on your hub. Put in some breakpoints to see who and when they are occurring

Comment: When you say manually deactivating a user, how are you doing this?

Comment: have you got `app.MapSignalR();` in your `Startup.cs`

Comment: @lzzy.Yes I did. I get the initial count displayed too.

Comment: @cdslnte. By manually running tsql. I put the Overrides. They are hit in this order - OnRecon, OnConn, GetCount

Comment: If your breakpoints are being hit when you debug then that's a good start. Try hooking up a button on the page which calls a JS function `$.connection.hub.stop();`.  `notify.client.stopClient = function () {` this line is wrong, you just need to stop the connection. I suggest some more reading of the [SignalR Docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signalr is not watching your database for changes. So when you just set the user to inactive in the database, it means nothing to Signalr. Your 3 clients are still connected.

To get the desired result add something like this to your Hub

```
public override OnConnected()
{
  // Increase the active user count in the db 
  IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerHub>();
  Clients.All.broadcastCount(DB.GetCount());
  return base.OnConnected();
}

public override OnDisconnected() 
{
    //Decrease the connected user count in the db
  IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerHub>();
  Clients.All.broadcastCount(DB.GetCount());
  return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

Then when you connect and disconnect your clients, the hub will notify connected clients.

You will need to disconnect in a way that SignalR will catch, so you can't just change a flag in the database. Try calling `$.connection.hub.stop();` from your client.

[This](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnectclientfromserver) link goes into more detail on it.

If you say the `dependency_OnChange` event is fired after you update in the database, then Instead of calling `SendNotifications();`, call a hub method, specifically `NotifyAllClients(...)`

Comment: Tried your suggestion. But did not work. On Page load, I see the count as 3. Then I manually run an update command to deactivate a user. The count on page should change to 2 without refreshing, right? It still shows 3.  I have updated the code in question

Comment: Can you show the code that deactivates the user? I'm assuming your initial count is 3 because you have 3 clients(browsers) open and not just because the count in your database is 3?

Comment: There are 3 records in DB & all 3 are active. Hence the initial 3. Then I run `Update Users set Active=0 where PKUserId=1`

Comment: Again, Signalr is not watching your database for changes. You need to start and stop the connections in client code. You can keep a list of connected clients in your DB and broadcast the count whenever required, but the connecting and disconnecting of clients needs to be done from a client.

Comment: Did not work. I have modified my question with a simpler example/code. Please have a look

Comment: Thank you!That worked. But here is a concern. It is hitting database twice on page load & multiple times on running the update. Why. Is this expected or a bad code

Comment: That depends on the rowcount in `DummyData` - when you run this `update DummyData set Message='hello world'` the `dependency_OnChange` presumably will fire for each row updated. Anyway that's probably worth another question if you can't figure it out after some debugging.