# Signalr call hangs browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Following an example here,
http://www.venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/

```
  $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.messagesHub;

        //debugger;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
            getMyMessages();
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            //alert("connection started");
            getMyMessages();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });


    function getMyMessages() {
        var tbl = $('#mesTable');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetMyMessages',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
        }).error(function () {

        });
    }
```

I am having above code for signalr. When I am running this on my local machine it works fine but when I deploy it on IIS and test with multiple users, the browser is not responding.

Can you please tell where I am going wrong with this

---

Hub

```
     [HubMethodName("sendMessages")]
            public static void SendMyMessages()
            {
                IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagesHub>();
                context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
            }

----------------------------------------------------------------------
public IEnumerable<Messages> GetAllMessages()
        {
            var messages = new List<Messages>();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                connection.Open();

using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [DoctorId], [DisplayName], [EmptyMessage], [Date] FROM [dbo].[Messages]", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;

                    var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                      messages.Add(item: new DocNotification { Id = (int)reader["Id"], DoctorId = (int)reader["DoctorId"], DisplayName = reader["DisplayName"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)reader["Message"] : "";
                    }
                }

            }
            return messages;
        }

        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                MessagesHub.SendMyMessages();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think by looking at your code, you need take out the logic of GetMyMessage REST service call and try to move that in your hub method updateMessages, This will be the great reference to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611795/how-to-notify-database-changes-with-signalr

Comment: @JenishZinzuvadiya my code is running well. It displays notification as soon as there is change in sql table. The issue is when multiple users are connected, the calls are repetitive. Sometime GetMyMessages is called 25 times for a single change and this doesn't occurs frequently